# How can I make text appear on next line instead of overflowing?

Tags: css, text, overflow

I have a fixed width div on my page that contains text. When I enter a long string of letters it overflows. I don't want to hide overflow I want to display the overflow on a new line, see below:

```
<div id="textbox" style="width:400px; height:200px;">
dfssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssfddddddddddddddddddddddsdffffffffffffffffsdffffffffffffffffdfssssssssssssdf
</div>
```

Is there anyway to disable overflow and put the overflowing text on a new line??? Twitter does something like this but I can't figure it out with CSS it's possible they are using Javascript.

Can anybody help with this??

Answer (score 326, accepted):

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

But it's CSS3 - http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/.

Comment: whilst it is CSS3, IIRC it works in most of the major browsers. +1

Comment: FYI: You can use either the 'normal' or 'break-word' value with the word-wrap property. 
Normal means the text will extend the boundaries of the box. 
Break-word means the text will wrap to next line.

Comment: `word-break: break-word;` worked for me.

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work but `white-space: initial;` does?

Comment: `word-wrap` is an unknown property. Did you mean `word-break`?

Comment: word-wrap: anywhere;

Comment: @GilEpshtain `word-wrap` is a known css property, check: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: I think, the author got perplexed with word-wrap and word-break property. 
It should be word-break. Here is the MDN
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Answer (score 357):

Just add

```
white-space: initial;
```

to the text, a line text will come automatically in the next line.

Comment: Works fine for most browsers, but to make it work in IE11 I had to use `white-space: normal;`

Comment: `white-space: initial;` Didn't work in IE 11 for me. Instead I've used `white-space: normal;` and it worked well in all browsers.

Comment: For my CSS grid based grid cells / responsive design I needed both `whitespace: initial` (or normal if supporting IE) and the `word-wrap: break-word` properties mentioned in this thread. -Thank You

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Saved a lot of time. Tried using word-wrap, overflow-wrap nothing worked, but this works fine in all major browsers.

Comment: this is kind of magic

Comment: white-space: normal; also works

Answer (score 6):

Try [the `<wbr>` tag](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) - not as elegant as the `word-wrap` property that others suggested, but it's a working solution until all major browsers (read IE) implement CSS3.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can stick one or more "soft hyphens" (`&#173;`) in your long unbroken strings. I doubt that old IE versions deal with that correctly, but what it's *supposed* to do is tell the browser about allowable word breaks that it can use if it has to.

Now, how exactly would you pick where to stuff those characters?  That depends on the actual string and what it means, I guess.

Comment: you can use min-width and width together to fix it like this width: min-content;
    min-width: 100%;