# How to get an inline-block element to expand downward?

Tags: html, list, css, erb

I have an erb block that prints a list with two elements, a `.list-number` and an `.list-item`, and I'm inserting `...<br>` after every `.list-item`. I want the list to display like so:

```
1. Item1...
2. Item2...
3. Really long
   item3...
4. Really really
   really long
   item4...
5. Item5...
```

But I'm having trouble with the `display` aspect. If I use `display:inline-block` like this:

```
//CSS
.list-number {position: relative; display: inline-block;)
.list-item {position: relative; max-width: 40px; display: inline-block;)
```

then the list prints like this:

```
1. Item1...
2. Item2...
   Really long
3. item3...
   Really really
   really long
4. item4...
5. Item5...
```

so the divs that extend past their limits expand upwards. And if I just replace `display:inline-block` with `display:inline`, then the `max-width` is ignored and the `list-item` just keeps going, like this:

```
1. Item1...
2. Item2...
3. Really long item3...
4. Really really really long item4...
5. Item5...
```

How can I get `.list-item` to be constrained by its `max-width`, but also expand downwards? I made a fiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/1ex75zvs/1/

Comment: Please provide an example of the **actual** HTML becuase a proper `ol` ordered list with a max-width would do this automatically without `inline-block`. http://jsfiddle.net/1ex75zvs/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are using `inline-block` and without an example of the actual HTML it's hard to be sure but a simple float would achieve this.

```css
.item-number, .list-item {
    float: left;
}
.item-number {
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.list-item {
    max-width:90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-number">1</div>
<div class="list-item">lorem</div>
<div class="item-number">2</div>
<div class="list-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
<div class="item-number">3</div>
<div class="list-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
<div class="item-number">4</div>
<div class="list-item">lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CSS' word-wrap; and add height: auto;

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ex75zvs/5/)

**CSS**

```
.list-item {
      word-wrap: break-word;
      height: auto;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587390/how-can-i-make-text-appear-on-next-line-instead-of-overflowing)

[Source](http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/)

Comment: You re-posted the same fiddle I posted in my question. The code you added doesn't appear the behavior, in neither the 'inline' nor the 'inline-block' case. I updated my fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/1ex75zvs/2/

Comment: It works with inline-block, or you only want to use display: inline?