# How to prevent the overlapping of two input labels in splitLayout, Shiny, R?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, selectinput

The `ui` of the following example contains four `selectInput`. The last two of them are in a `splitLayout`. I noticed that, when I launch the app, the label of the last two would overlap if the window size is not large enough, as the first screenshot shows. Is it possible to make the label of the input in `splitLayout` dynamically change depends on the width of the window? A comparison would be the first two `selectInput`. As shown in the second screenshot, when I reduce the window width, the label would change to two lines. I would like to have the same behavior for the last two `selectInput` in `splitLayout`.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "A", label = "This is a long lebel with lots of words", choices = letters[1:5], selected = "a"),
    selectInput(inputId = "B", label = "This is a long lebel with lots of words", choices = letters[1:5], selected = "a"),
    splitLayout(
      selectInput(inputId = "C", label = "This is a long lebel with lots of words", choices = letters[1:5], selected = "a"),
      selectInput(inputId = "D", label = "This is a long lebel with lots of words", choices = letters[1:5], selected = "a"),
      # Expand the menu in splitLayout
      # From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098855/7669809
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                              .shiny-split-layout > div {
                                overflow: visible;
                              }
                              ")))
  )
  )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){

}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**First screenshot:**

[image]

**Sceond screenshot:**

[image]

**Update**

@Simran has pointed out that `overflow: visible` is the cause of this issue. However, I need this to expand my menu in the `selectInput` based on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098855/7669809

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587390/how-can-i-make-text-appear-on-next-line-instead-of-overflowing

Comment: @Simran Thanks for pointing out this post. Although I believe you the post you mentioned is relevant to my question, that post did not mention anything about `Shiny`. I have no experience in HTML. If you don't mind, could you help me by developing the proper `div` line that I can insert to my R code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume using `fluidRow()` with `column()` is an option for you.

Then you could use:

```
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 4,
        selectInput(...)
      ),
      column(width = 4,
        selectInput(...)
      )
    )
```

**Note 1:**

You can control the width of an input by the width parameter of `column()`.

**Note 2:**

Sidenote: If you want to use the full width of 12, you also have to set the `mainPanel()` to 12, see e.g. here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44214927/3502164

**Full app - reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "A", label = "This is a long lebel with lots of words", choices = letters[1:5], selected = "a"),
    selectInput(inputId = "B", label = "This is a long lebel with lots of words", choices = letters[1:5], selected = "a"),
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 4,
        selectInput(inputId = "C", label = "This is a long lebel with lots of words", choices = letters[1:5], selected = "a")        
      ),
      column(width = 4,
        selectInput(inputId = "D", label = "This is a long lebel with lots of words", choices = letters[1:5], selected = "a")
      )
    ),
      # Expand the menu in splitLayout
      # From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098855/7669809
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                              .shiny-split-layout > div {
                                display: inline-block;
                              }
                              ")))
    )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session){

}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Good solution. Thanks. I will reward you the bounty when the system allows me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `overflow: visible`. This is what is making the text spill over the div. I see that here in your code:

```
.shiny-split-layout > div {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have given you an upvote. But `overflow: visible` is necessary for me to expand the menu in my `selectInput`. At least this is what I learned from this post "https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098855/7669809". Is there a way to expand the menu while preventing text spill?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the generated HTML output from your code and add styling that targets more specific element. I suspect the `div` you are targeting with this style is a wrapper around other elements and needs to have its overflow left alone to behave like a container. Perhaps a more specific element needs `overflow:visible` but that strikes me as a hacky approach to what is likely a different layout need.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Good point. I will look into the `div` more.